# Copying files to a Linux bootable ISO

Tags: boot, iso

I know it sounds the simplest thing you can do but not really right now.

### Goal

My goal is to be able to do file operations without causing problems for a bootable ISO, since the builtin ISO reader (in an Ubuntu VM) seems to make it unbootable. As  I rename a file in a bootable Linux (Ubuntu/Linux Mint) ISO with the builtin program, I can't boot from it using an VM.

### Question

Is there something from the command line that I can do? I've tried using `mount`ing the ISO but it's read-only.

Comment: Nope. That's a feature, not a bug, of ISO images.

Comment: I didn't say it was a bug or a feature.